# transmogrifier without plone

Tags: plone, transmogrifier

I'd like to user c.transmogrifier outside plone. How far is it from being plone-independent?

Actually I see very few plone-related imports and plone-only-specific code inside the [trunk](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.transmogrifier/trunk) so that it seems feasible.

Is there any roadmap or any todo/advice list for getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a runner for executing transmogrifier outside of plone via a commandline tool. At the  moment that runner is part of [funnelbweb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/funnelweb). You can use the funnelweb script to run your own pipelines via "funnelweb --pipeline=mypipeline.cfg" 
However we are in the process of migrating that code into a general module called [mr.migrator](https://github.com/collective/mr.migrator). Mr.migrator will be both a commandline runner for transmogrifier pipelines and also a Plone UI to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

`collective.transmogrifier` only depends on CMFCore, not Plone. I do have plans to make that dependency optional though, I simply haven't had the time to do so yet.